# ReactJS Create a SVG element from String

Tags: reactjs, svg

I need to create a SVG from a string in order to make this new SVG  to be nested within another SVG object. I've followed [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString).

I added this code:

```
const data =
      '<svg height="210" width="400"><path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" /></svg>';

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const dataParsed = parser.parseFromString(data, "image/svg+xml");
    const parsed = dataParsed.firstChild;

    console.log(parsed);
```

What I need is to reproduce [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-roman-88zcjy?file=/src/App.js), but the nested SVG is a string. That is to say [this other sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-morning-695bmk?file=/src/App.js).

The first approach works as expected, the second one doesn't work at all because it yells at me `Objects are not valid as a React child`. I'm kind of stucked here. Any hint on how to solve this?